# Rails devise sign in not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a problem - recently I created User with devise gem. Sadly, the "sign_in" button does not really work properly - after visiting sin_in page and clicking on sign in button nothing happens! It does not matter if I enter my email and password for signing in. I checked the logs and after clicking sign up button there are no changes in logs or on the terminal with server running on! So I guess it does not send any request? But the problem occurs only after I visit the login page the first time, after refreshing it all works as intended. Please help me, I have no idea what may cause such weird behaviour.

EDIT: Oddly enough, I noticed that only after heading to login page from my main page the problem occurs - If I proceed to login page simply by typing its address instead of clicking on sing in link in browser it works. But addresses after both actions are the same, so I have no idea... There are my welcome view:

```
<div id="homepage">
  <header class="cf">
    <h1 class="logo"><%= link_to "E-LEARN", "#" %></h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Watch guides", root_path %></li>
        <% unless user_signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "My Account", current_user %></li>
        <% end %>
        <li><%= link_to "Add tutorial", "#" %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper-skinny" id="welc">
    <h1>Learn programming from others, or share your experience with novices.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <%= link_to "Learn something", new_user_registration_path , class: "button button-highlight" %>
    <%= link_to "Share experience", "#", class: "button button-dark"%>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are my files:
application controller:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :description, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

migration:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :guides
  validates :username, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'welcome#index'
  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:show, :index] do
    resources :guides
  end

end
```

and gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

routes:

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                               Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                                         welcome#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
             user_guides GET    /users/:user_id/guides(.:format)          guides#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/guides(.:format)          guides#create
          new_user_guide GET    /users/:user_id/guides/new(.:format)      guides#new
         edit_user_guide GET    /users/:user_id/guides/:id/edit(.:format) guides#edit
              user_guide GET    /users/:user_id/guides/:id(.:format)      guides#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/guides/:id(.:format)      guides#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/guides/:id(.:format)      guides#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/guides/:id(.:format)      guides#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                          users#index
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#show
```

and my login view (devise/sessions/new.html.erb):

```
<%= render 'shared/header' %>

<div class="banner" >
</div>

<div class="wrapper-skinny">
  <h2>Log in</h2>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div class="field" id="checkbox">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div></div><br>
    <% end -%>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like turbolinks problem.

1. Remove turbolinks gem from your Gemfile
2. Run bundle install
3. In app/views/layouts/application.html.haml set turbolinks to `false` like that:

`= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false`

`= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false`

or remove them.

4. remove `//= require turbolinks` from app/assets/javascripts/application.js
5. Restart server

Comment: You are right! Doing what you described solved the problem. But do you know if there is any other solution? I mean not involving disabling turbolinks, because I feel like it is ignoring the problem and the way around it.

Comment: @JakubKopyś I'll find it out, but also you should make sure that turbolinks are your must-have. In most cases they aren't.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little what will happen by above changes and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

@JakubKopyś Here is nice way to exclude single link from turbolinks without removing gem (from turbolinks github repo):

"By default, all internal HTML links will be funneled through Turbolinks, but you can opt out by marking links or their parent container with data-no-turbolink. For example, if you mark a div with data-no-turbolink, then all links inside of that div will be treated as regular links. If you mark the body, every link on that entire page will be treated as regular links."

`<div id="some-div" data-no-turbolink>
  <a href="/">Home (without Turbolinks)</a>
</div>`

Comment: Thank You very much, It was exactly what I needed! I really appreciate Your help sir. Have a nice day.

Comment: @JakubKopyś Nie ma sprawy ;)